# CSS for Auto margin among buttons in div on different resolutions

Tags: jquery, css

I have 3 buttons in a `div`, while checking on different resolutions its responsive, but on some screens last button comes under first two buttons without any margin among them.

Is there any way to provide this margin without using media queries.

[image: image attached]

Comment: Please provide the HTML and CSS currently used for those elements.

Comment: @4castle Is the HTML and CSS really necessary? :)

Comment: When you mention media queries, is it because you don't want the bottom margin when they aren't wrapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `margin-bottom` on the buttons. Make sure that the buttons are of `display: inline-block;`:

```css
.btn {display: inline-block; margin: 0 0 10px; width: 200px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px; border: 0;}
.one {background: #99f;}
.two {background: #9f9;}
```

```html
<button class="btn one">One</button>
<button class="btn one">Two</button>
<button class="btn two">Three</button>
```

**Preview**

[image]

You may adjust the `margin-bottom` to the space between the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) & you don't have to worry about it!

Example Snippet :

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="row text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">Button One</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">Button Two</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">Button Three</button>
</div>
```

Comment: **1.** I don't think the OP uses bootstrap. **2.** OP mentions they do not wanna use `@media` queries. :)

Comment: Bootstrap requires jQuery. Don't forget to include that :) In the long run, this is probably what the OP should use for a responsive site.

Comment: To solve a simple method, you wanna load a huge framework. :) I agree with you, but... :) Do you understand what I am trying to tell? :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, I agree. Perhaps this could be a helpful comment instead.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes I got what you are telling but to make a responsive site easily its better to use bootstrap or skeleton... etc.